# How to save a Treeview data as excel file in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, tkinter, treeview

I have some data in my `Treeview` Form which is binded to my SQLite database, I wonder if there is a way to save my `Treeview`'s data as an excel file in my computer.

```
mytree = ttk.Treeview(frame_busqueda, height=19, column=('column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5', 'column6'), show='headings', style="Custom.Treeview")
            mytree.pack()
style = ttk.Style()

style.configure("Custom.Treeview.Heading",
                             foreground="green", relief="flat", font='arial 10 bold')
style.map("Custom.Treeview.Heading", relief=[('active', 'groove'), ('pressed', 'sunken')])


mytree.heading("#1", text="ID CARD")
mytree.column("#1", minwidth=0, width=103, stretch=NO)
mytree.heading("#2", text="NAME")
mytree.column("#2", minwidth=0, width=200, stretch=NO)
mytree.heading("#3", text="SURNAME") 

def savetreeview():
     with open("new.csv", "w", newline='') as myfile:
          csvwriter = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',')

          for row_id in mytree.get_children():
              row = mytree.item(row_id)['values']
              csvwriter.writerow(row)
              print(row)
```

I was trying to use csv to try to get the rows, and it shows me all my `Treeview` data as output, but actually what I want is to save my `Treeview`'s data as an excel file in my computer. Thanks

Comment: @CoolCloud it shows me my Treeview values ONLY as output perferctly when I run my program, but what I want is to save all my treeview data as an excel file in my computer, I've read about pandas but I got stucked mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple with `pandas`, all you have to do is create a writer and use it to write the csv to excel, like:

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('nameofexcelfiletocreate.xlsx') # Creates this excel file
df = pd.read_csv('new.csv') # Reads the csv and makes a dataframe

df.to_excel(writer,'sheet1') # Writes the dataframe to excel file
writer.save() # Saves the file
```

This will create a new excel file with your csv converted to excel. Keep a note you have to install `openpyxl` for this to function:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

So your function would be something like:

```
def call():
    cols = ['ID CARD','NAME','SURNAME'] # Your column headings here
    path = 'read.csv'
    excel_name = 'newfile.xlsx'
    lst = []
    with open(path, "w", newline='') as myfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',')
        for row_id in mytree.get_children():
            row = mytree.item(row_id,'values')
            lst.append(row)
        lst = list(map(list,lst))
        lst.insert(0,cols)
        for row in lst:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_name)
    df = pd.read_csv(path)
    df.to_excel(writer,'sheetname')
    writer.save()
```

Comment: Do I have to create an excel file before run that code? or that function will create and save it as new file?, and second quesion, Do I have to modify the **values** here? `row = mytree.item(row_id)['values']` I tried to run it but I got error, also tried to modify the 'values' with my treeview columns also gave me an error or it's because I need to have a file in my computer with 'newfile.xlsx' and 'sheetname' ?

Comment: @Paul Nope, it will create such a file

Comment: `row = mytree.item(row_id)['values']` Will give list of all inputs per row, what is wrong? Update question with new errors.

Comment: It is giving me some error, once I run my programan my Buttons dissapeared, but I got two excel files in my main project file **new.csv** and **newfile.xlsx** , the new.csv has stored my treeview data but only in one cell, and the newfile.xlsx gave me an error 'excel cannot open the file....because the format or file extension isnt valid'

Comment: I also get this error when I run my program "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file"

Comment: I have updated the answer, did you try it out.

Comment: wow man it's working now, just two details, my 'newfile.xlsx' is not saving my treeview headers (id, name, surname, etc) insted it is taking the first row of my values as header, and second detail, I wonder if It's possible every time I push my button 'save' to save in different excel files insted using always the same 'newfile.xlsx' , So it should be like I get a box asking me where I want to save it and which name, and after saving it then it just show 'saved succsefully' or if there isnt data in my treeview just show 'no data to save'

Comment: @Paul I have updated the answer with part of the code that is relevant to this question, for the rest of the answer, you will have to ask a new question.

Comment: Ok mate, I'll create a new question

Comment: Sure mate, I also have posted a new question, please checkout =') , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def saveExcel():
    workbook = load_workbook(filename='problem record.xlsx')
    sheet=workbook['Sheet1']
    sheet.delete_rows(idx=2, amount=15)
    for row_id in treeview.get_children():
        row = treeview.item(row_id)['values']
        sheet.append(row)
    workbook.save(filename='problem record.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
Based on these,i simplified the program and relized directly save to excel.