# In my tkinter tool, I have treeview with parent and child and want to save data

Tags: python, tkinter, save, treeview, opencsv

I have developed a Tkinter window with treeview where I can enter data manually to treeview which has a parent and also child data. The Window also has some labels which are also entered manually. Now I am trying to include the option to save treeview data and label data with csv file type. I should also be able to open the saved file. My tree view data is grouped like the following:

Parent1

```
  child1 

  child2
```

Parent2

```
  child1 

  child2

  child3
```

and I have to labeles:
sys = Label(main, text="abc")
sps = Label(main, text="xxx")

I am able to only save the data of the child but not able to save the parent data and the labels in my window.
How to save and load these?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66442821/13382000). Ignore the convertion to xlsx, just check the csv part.

Comment: @coolCloud I tried the following link but it did not work in my case.

Comment: Which is the label data.

Comment: I have made the changes to the question. If my question is not clear, please let me know, I will post my entire code. @coolCloud